# Sqlite insert if not in Exclusion table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to go an insert into the Records Table if a value does not exist in an exclusion table.

> ```
>       INSERT INTO Records(Front, Back) VALUES ( ?, ?)
>         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT VALUE FROM Exclusion WHERE INSTR(VALUE, Back))
> ```

So if a portion of VALUE found in the Exclusion table is found in Back then do not insert.

The format of Exclusion Table is Key, Value

When I attempt to run this none of my records get inserted.  This also needs to work and insert all records if the Exclusion Table is empty.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT INTO...VALUES..` statement. 
Instead use `INSERT INTO...SELECT..` like this:

```
INSERT INTO Records(Front, Back) 
SELECT frontvalue, backvalue
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT VALUE FROM Exclusion WHERE INSTR(VALUE, backvalue) > 0)
```

You can use the operator `LIKE` instead of the function `INSTR()`:

```
WHERE VALUE LIKE '%' || backvalue || '%'
```

Comment: I tried and i am erroring.  The actual tables have more fields and I am doing this in c++.  My code is

Comment: string sql = "INSERT INTO RegistryActionTable (Front, Back, Hive, NormalizedKey, UserName, SignalFlag, ProcessID, IsProtectionOn, IsBSSMember, ProcessTime, IsNew, IsSuccess, DataValue) ";
   sql += "SELECT ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
   
   sql += "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT VALUE FROM Configuration WHERE INSTR(VALUE, ?) > 0)";

Comment: Remove the parentheses from `select (?, ?, ...)` and keep the spaces between statements and try again. You need to pass the parameter for backvalue twice.

Comment: I removed the ( and that worked.  I am binding the backvalue twice.  Seems that the records are inserting but hard to tell if the results are correct.  ie I put a value of 'a' in the config table and my records still have a's in them

Comment: *I put a value of 'a' in the config table and my records still have a's in them* are you sure you want `INSTR(VALUE, backvalue) > 0` and not `INSTR(backvalue, VALUE) > 0`?

Comment: I think it is right - backvalue would be like ThisThing\12345 while value would be 12345

Comment: Then it is `INSTR(backvalue, VALUE) > 0`